# Unable to install rJava 3.3.0 on RHEL 6.7

Tags: r, linux, rhel

Recently we have downgraded R(latest) to 3.3.0 to RHEL.

Which requires to install xlsx and other rJava dependent packages, though I have deep dived into every possible duplicate and tried all options.

Details:

Command Executed

> R CMD javareconf

Error:

`.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib64/R/lib64/R/lib/libR.a(CommandLineArgs.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libjri.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory /tmp/RtmpH1WhQR/R.INSTALL4a1266bbb309/rJava/jri/src`'
`

Net search: I searched and found following link
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2171 suggests to use 
export CXXFLAGS=-fPIC

but no luck also I do not see CMakeCache.txt in the R folder, still not clear which piece I am missing and any help will be highly appreciated.

**NOTE: This might seem to be a duplicate, but seriously I have already tried all the related/relevant posts on stackoverflow.**

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this, by manually placing the rJava folder(which I had in a different environment while we used R latest version), while entering into R add this following command before installing rJava dependant libraries:

```
.libPaths("/usr/lib64/R/library")
```

> Change the path to the path where R is installed.

[image]

Hope this helps.